# How to Make MonoTouch Cross Platform

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios

I am evaluating the technology our company will be using for Android and iOS development in the future.

As such I am looking into cross platform options as well as native development.

I understand that MonoTouch shares the same backend code, but the UI has to be duplicated.

I started my first MonoTouch project, and cannot understand how this would work. The project is in Visual Studio, and the MonoTouch for iOS has to run on mac. A VS solution wouldn't work on mac, so I was wondering how it looks on mac and how you share the code between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, there's not an easy way of working with Mono for Android and MonoTouch when you are using Mono for Android on Visual Studio, Xamarin have two example applications (Tasky and TipCalc) that use shared code and logic but have different UIs, you can find these on their GitHub account: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples

There are various ways of sharing code across the three platforms, Jonas has a great video on achieving this that you can watch here: http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/cross-platform-mobile-ndc-2011/ and hopefully Xamarin will make this easier in the future by providing an out of the box way of opening MonoTouch projects in Visual Studio (although you'll still need a Mac), that way you will have an easy way of coding between iOS, Android and WP7.

Comment: So are you saying that you have to use the MonoDevelop IDE to make it cross platform? Well at least to open up the same project on both?

Comment: Yes, you can use MonoDevelop on a Mac and code both Android and iOS applications and have them both open in one solution but different projects.

Answer (score 1):

You would share the code using a source code control system or live using a shared drive. Some developers like to edit their code using Visual studio and tools like Resharper but still compile on the Mac. There are various tutorials on the web how to acheive this.

Comment: I've done this exact thing, except using dropbox. I have found this to work extremely well. For the record, with a little bit of extra work, it will can BUILD/COMPILE in Visual Studio, it just won't run/debug.

Answer (score 1):

There is a platform called Monocross that is built on the Xamarin Mono base. It helps you layout your code in a fashion that makes it easier to make your app compatible with different platforms.

Comment: It would be located here: http://www.monocross.net. This is using the MVC pattern. If you prefer the MVVM pattern, you can use: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross. This was forked by @slodge from the monocross project.